# Posting data from single view to two model classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have created Viewmodel class and created two properities(by using two model classes i.e from customerModel & addressModel) in that class.Then how to bind the data from view to model.

```
namespace customer2.Models
{
    public class customerdetails {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { set; get; }
        [Key] public int customerid { set; get; }
        public string customername { set; get; }
    }
    public class addressdetails
    {
        public int addressno { set; get; }
        public string street { set; get; }
        public string landmark { set; get; }
        public int pincode { set; get; }

    }
    public class MkContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<customerdetails> customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<addressdetails> address { get; set; }
    }
    public class customerviewmodel
    {
        public customerdetails cd { set; get; }
        public List<addressdetails> ad { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] of the Viewmodel class you've created, this will allow any answers to address your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a ViewModel with Combined values of other two data Models for what values we are capture as input in Form
2. place the ViewModel as a parameter in the controller action method.
3. Inside the action method, you can bind the values to the two different data models.

**HTML Form**

> ```
> <form action='controller/SaveCustomer' method='post'>
>   <input Type='text' name='FirstName' />
>   <input Type='text' name='LastName' />
>   <input Type='text' name='Address' />
> </form>
> ```

**View Model**

```
 Public Class CustViewModel {  
   public string FirstName {get; set;}  
   public string LastName{get; set;}   
   public string Address{get; set;} 
}
```

**Customer Data Model**

```
Public Class CustModel {  
       public string FirstName {get; set;}  
       public string LastName{get; set;}   
    }
```

**addressModel**

```
Public Class AddModel {              
       public string Address{get; set;} 
    }
```

**Controller Method**

```
Public ActionResult SaveCustomer(CustViewModel  Details)
{
    CustModel  Cust = new CustModel();
    AddModel  Add= new AddModel();

     Cust.FirstName= Details.FirstName; 
     Cust.LastName = Details.LastName;
     Add.Address = Details.Address ;

   return view();
}
```

***Or Else You Can directly add the model class in Controller***

**Controller Method**

```
 Public ActionResult SaveCustomer(CustModel CustDetails, AddModel  AddDetails)
    {
        //Do the Action

       return view();
    }
```

Comment: hello bro! i want user to input 'n' no of address